# How to tell what encryption is used in PDF?

Tags: pdf, encryption, aes

I'm trying to read PDF in my app. I've stumbled upon AES-encrypted PDFs.

As far as I undestood from the PDF reference, in AES scheme, strings and streams should be padded up to multiple of 16 length. First 16 bytes are the IV in unencoded form.

However, in my PDF, strings have lengths, which are not multiple of 16. Decryption of such strings predictably fails.

Here are the details of the PDF:

Header:

```
%PDF-1.6
```

Encrypt dictionary:

```
<</Length 128/Filter/Standard/O(...)/P -1340/R 3/U(...)/V 2>>
```

So, PDF version is 1.6, encryption version is 2 and revision is 3 - under this condition, PDF reference states that AES scheme is used.

Example of encoded string:

```
Author(Í¡c$5N8 ¶ŽÜß*ç»«ÈÙÏ)
```

which has the length of 29.

Note that I'm able to verify user password as stated in algorithm "Authenticating the user password", and it shows to be valid.

**EDIT**:
The only logical answer would be "Because it is not AES-encrypted". Indeed, when forcing encryption to RC4, PDF decrypts just fine.

So the question is rather "How to tell if AES or RC4 is used?"

Comment: To me the PDF specification seems to say that AES starts being an option in revision (**R**) 4, not 3. In revision 4 the crypt filter **StdCF** key **CFM** value **AESV2** indicates AES-128. Revision 5 implies AES-256.

Comment: Here is what I found in specs:
"The following algorithms are used when encrypting data in a PDF file:... The AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) algorithm (beginning with PDF 1.6)"
and:
"If revision 4 is specified, the standard security handler supports crypt filters (see Section 3.5.4, “Crypt Filters”)"
As far as I understand, crypt filters allow overriding default filter for a specific object, no?

Comment: *If revision 4 is specified* ... exactly, and your sample specifies revision 3.

Comment: It seems you are viewing the output of the encryption algorithms as characters using a Unicode encoding (probably UTF-8). The output of encryption however is *binary* and may include bytes that are not representing valid UTF-8 as well as non-printable characters such as control characters. Could you display the encrypted `Author` as hexadecimal bytes instead?

Comment: @mkl: Revision 4 enables use of Crypt Filter, which allow overriding default crypt parameters. No crypt filters => use only default parameters.
Seems that I mistakenly assumed that PDF version 1.6 sets AES as a default cipher. More likely that RC4 is always the default cipher.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: I'm aware that strings can contain UTF8. However, this is not the case - when using RC4 as a cipher, this string decrypts into a correct string.

Comment: For such a small string that could be simply luck hweom. The string representation will consist of random bytes (because of the random salt and the cipher). If they represent printable characters or not depends on chance. Besides that, with RC4 you would just miss a character in the output; for CBC mode encryption it will fail because of the length issue.